# Responsive IFrame Video

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am trying to embed a google drive video in my website. At the moment the frame is responsive, however when viewing on a mobile device the video is not shrunk down to the frame size. This means that a user can only see the top corner of the video. 
How do I make the vid fit?

```
<div style="text-align:center; position: relative; height: 0; padding-bottom: 50%; overflow: hidden;"><iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L2SPIlBhglFhGenByihjkgFcEVx1d2Th/preview" width="960" height="540"></iframe></div>
```

[Screenshot of Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGYxz.png)

Comment: can you share some more code or least screenshot, its difficult to analyze what are you trying to say

Comment: Screenshot is added

Answer (score 0):

tried adding this in the head tag?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```